# Bug in review audits

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I found a minor bug in "this is just a test" reviews.

I was reviewing a **late answer** on Stack Oveflow, and a review audit appeared. After reading the question to see if the answer had anything to do with it, I clicked on "show comments" on the **question**. The "Congrats, you passed" message appeared immediately and allowed me to continue to the next review, with the message being something similar to "Thanks for deciding to leave the user feedback."

Is showing more comments supposed to count as a pass for a review audit?

Comment: You just passed the test. You did not blindly take an inappropriate action.

Comment: I don't know, I wouldn't really qualify that as taking action. I just wanted to read the question's comments, not review the answer. It caught me by surprise because I actually thought the answer was okay, I just wanted to understand if it's the correct one. Probably would've failed otherwise.

Comment: The audits are in place to stop the worst of the reviewers. Those who blindly click. Perhaps this particular approval should only happen if you actually try to add a comment (is that ever possible from a review queue?). But still, the fact that you looked beyond what was presented to you means you're not as terrible as those the audits try to stop.

Comment: So you just want someone to change the status to "you failed the review"?

Comment: Not failed. But perhaps it shouldn't do anything when you read comments, only when you try to write one? It kind of lets you easily game the system. Press the `show comments` button and find out if this is a test or not.

Comment: moral of the story?  blindly click on the `add comment` button before you blindly click on the `no action needed` button

Comment: These aren't called test reviews. Their called audits. I'd change the question wording to that to attract more attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is showing more comments supposed to count as a pass for a review audit?

Strictly-speaking, no - it's supposed to expand comments. Adding a comment is supposed to count as a pass...

...But since they both piggyback on one link, there's no simple way to differentiate between them.

As others have noted, audits are primarily there to educate folks who might think that clicking the same button 200 times in a row was helpful otherwise. If you're actually bothering to read the post and then go on to the comments, you've kinda *already* passed.